# How can I get business reviews from google maps using google-maps-api?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I search for food (for example) in google maps, i get a bunch of businesses, each one having reviews... like in Yelp. I am trying to get those business' reviews so I can use them as training data to my NLP review classifier.

... and also does the api support only javascript?  can i do something to use the API with Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google dont make this available by any API.

v3 of the javascript api - only supports javascript - its designed to run in a web-browser. So makes absolutely no sense to run in java. (although can have a browser in a java app)

... other apis can be called from java.